# Find a general solution of the given differential equation: $y\:\mathrm{d}x-4(x+y^6)\:\mathrm{d}y=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I need to solve the equation above using the method of finding the integrating factor. I got $y'$ by itself, but how do I simplify the value in front of the $y$ in order to use it as $P(x)$? Thoroughly confused here.

$$
\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x} = \frac{y}{4x+4y^6}
$$

Comment: $x(y)=2y^6+Cy^4$.

Comment: In general, $x'(y)=\dfrac{A~x+B~y^n}{D~y}$ has the solution $x(y)=\dfrac{B~y^n}{D~n-A}+C~y^{A/D}.$

Comment: For $n=\dfrac AD$ we replace $\dfrac1{D~n-A}$ with $\dfrac{\ln y}D$ in the above formula.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flip the equation, solve it in this form:
$$
\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}y} = \frac{4x+4y^6}{y}
$$
then you can use the integration factor to find $P(y)$, and the solution for x in terms of y, which is the general solution.

Comment: Yup that worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Equivalently,

$$\dfrac{dx}{dy} - \dfrac{4}{y}x = 4y^5$$

Which has integrating factor

$$I(y) = \exp \left(-\displaystyle\int^y \dfrac{4}{y'}dy'\right) = y^{-4}$$

Multiplying through the above ODE by the integrating factor yields,

$$ \dfrac{d}{dy}[xy^{-4}] =4y$$

Which is easily solvable for $y$.